# Firestore doesn't creates parent Document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a Webapp that lets users save ideas.
When a idea gets saved, it is saved in the collection "users" which contains their user uid. Under the users Id is then again a collection named "ideas" created in which finally the ideas get saved.
The problem is, that when i save the idea, everything works fine, but the User ID is greyed out.
This leads to that i can't retrieve the ideas for a user, because the user id document isn't created.

The view in firestore:
[image]

[image]

The function that i use to create the documents:
[image]

The function to retrieve the data:

[image]

I can retrieve the ideas of a user correctly, when i create the users id entry manualy.
Do i need to check for the existence of a users document before saving the ideas into it and if it doesn't exists create it?
Or is there a better way im not aware of?

Comment: A parent document is not technically container of the sub collections. It's just a namespace. Can you share your code to fetch ideas of a user that is not working ?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the user document, otherwise you will create a dangling collection without a parent document.

The id is greyed out, because the document does not actually exist and is only displayed because of the collection under it.